# Angular Component doesn't re-render subscribed data when page is refreshed

Tags: angular, http

I have a component that runs an http subscription to a service inside `ngOnInIt` and fetches users and displays them. This works fine when navigated to from the header, but when the user refreshes the page, the data doesn't render right away even though the subscription was executed and data was returned.

Instead I have to hover over the menu item and the html renders.

I've looked at `ngZone` and `ChangeDetectorRef`, but not sure what is the best way to tackle this issue.

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.auth.getAllUsers()
 .subscribe(results => {   
   console.log(results);
   this.testUsers = results.message;
   console.log(this.testUsers);
 }
 }, err => {
   if (err.error) {
   this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
   this.isError = true;
 }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row"*ngFor="let user of testUsers; let i = index">
  <div class=" list-group" style="width:30%">
  <p class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
  {{user?.UserName}}
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

```js
// Service
getAllUsers() {
  return this.http.get<User>(API_USERS_URL + '/GetUsers')
  .pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError('Error Grabbing Users', 'message')));
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your `getAllUsers` code as well?

Comment: Your component has `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`  ?

Comment: @abney317 I added

Comment: So does it work but it just takes a moment for your data to load?

Comment: I loads automatically in the console after the page refresh. The html just doesn't render until I hover over the menu option.

Comment: @Eldar No it doesn't.

Comment: No errors in the console either? A stackblitz would help to see what's going on here.

Comment: Nope. I'll try and get one set up.